# Android unit testing : calling a method from fragment which uses context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit4

I am trying to call a method that is defined in a fragment from a unit test class. The method uses 'getString()' method to access a string resource, because of this I'm getting below exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{5474c6c} not attached to a context.
```

Unit test snippet

```
class Test {

lateinit var mfragment: MyActivity.MyFragment

@Before
fun setupFragment(){
    minorWorksElectricalFragment1 = MyActivity.MyFragment()
}

@Test
fun extraInstrumentValidationStatus_withMultifunction_allOtherNA(){
    val status = mfragment!!.getExtraInstrumentValidationStatus("Testvalue",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA")
    Assert.assertThat(status,`is`(true))
}
```

}

Method definition

```
public boolean getExtraInstrumentValidationStatus(String multiFunctionalValue,
                                                      String insulationResisValue,
                                                      String continuityValue,
                                                      String earthElectrodeValue,
                                                      String earthFaultValue,
                                                      String rcdValue) {

        String[] nonMultiFunctionalValues = new String[]{insulationResisValue,
                continuityValue,
                earthElectrodeValue,
                earthFaultValue,
                rcdValue};

        if (!multiFunctionalValue.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.NA)) &&
                !StringUtils.isEmpty(multiFunctionalValue.trim())) {
            for (String value : nonMultiFunctionalValues) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.NA)) ||
                        StringUtils.isEmpty(value.trim())) return false;
            }
        } else {
            for (String value : nonMultiFunctionalValues) {
                if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.NA))) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest the best option to initialize the fragment with the context in a unit test?

Answer (score 2):

Unit test should run separately from Android framework.
The best practice is to separate bussiness logic to be independent from Android so it can be Unit tested.

If you want to test Android-specific stuff, look up "Android Instrumented tests"
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the Activity where the Fragment is attached.
Also, check if the activity!=null before initializing the Fragment.